# how to get multiple stock's info at once using yfinance

Tags: python, yfinance

My question is similar to the following.
[Get info on multiple stock tickers quickly using yfinance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71161902/get-info-on-multiple-stock-tickers-quickly-using-yfinance)

But I would like to know how to do it as a group request rather than by iteration as in the link above. I know that I can get multiple stock price history as a one line command. But I would like to do that with the "info" part of a yfinance ticker instead.

I tried the following:

```
import yfinance as yf
tickers_list=['IBM','CSCO']
xx= yf.Tickers(tickers_list)
xx.tickers['CSCO'].info  # works
xx.tickers.info # fails
```

The last line gives an error message AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'info'

Comment: Try this: `ticker_info_list = [];[ticker_info_dict.append(xx.tickers[ticker].info) for ticker in tickers_list]`